# How to send letters to all the recipients at once Apple Mail?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, email, automator

I have 100 open emails in Apple Mail. There will be one recipient for each email. Such a requirement is very important to me and can't be changed.

How can I automate the process of sending these emails with one or two clicks? I prefer not having to press 'Send' 100 times.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The send shortcut is ⇧⌘D. Hold this down to send the emails.